# IdentityServer4 sometimes returns 500 for google and microsoft authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

Sometimes google and microsoft authentication returns 500 on IdentityServer4.
Specifically, /signin-google and /signin-microsoft are returning 500 errors, and the situation is as follows

・About 3,000 requests per minute.
・About 80 of them return 500 errors.
・The rest return 301.

Do you know the cause?
Is there a problem with the number of accesses or the external authentication side?
Also, will upgrading to IdenityServer 6 and registering a license solve the problem?

Here is the code

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        AppSettings.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Caching.ClientStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Caching.ResourceStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Caching.CorsExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        })
            .AddRedirectUriValidator<RedirectUriValidator>()
            .AddInMemoryCaching()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),         // OIDC認証を使用 
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            })
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName),
            })
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryCaching()
            .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("Clients"))
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
        {
            config.LoginPath = "/Web/User/Login";
            config.LogoutPath = "/Web/User/Logout";
            config.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Common.LoginTimeoutSeconds);
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Common.TokenCreateKey)),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            };
        }).AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("GoogleClient:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("GoogleClient:ClientSecret");
        }).AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MicrosoftClient:ClientId");
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MicrosoftClient:ClientSecret");
        });

        services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication(); 
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is that you have these in the wrong order:

```
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication(); 
    app.UseIdentityServer();
```

Authorization should always be last:

```
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

If I am not wrong, you can also remove UseAuthentication() because UseIdentityServer adds that for you.